# checking if a key is present in a hashmap JSP Struts 2

Tags: jsp, dictionary, struts2, ognl

I have a hashmap in an action class. I am trying to check if a key is not present to display a particular text on screen. However, it is not working. below is the code:

```xml
<s:elseif test="%{#map[getCurrentYear()]==null && #map.key.equalsIgnoreCase(cdKey)}">
    <h4>
        2
        <s:text name="properties.msg.header" />
        <s:property value="currentYear"      />
    </h4>
</s:elseif>
```

I am not able to get what is wrong with the code.

Comment: What is `map`? What is `getCurrentYear()`? What is `#map.key`? What is `cdKey`? Show your code.

Comment: @Andrea I have a field defined in Action class with getter and setter. private String cdKey='cdKey' and private String cyQKey ='cyQKey' . I have one Hashmap - map <String, object> which is storing these keys. I am trying to check if cyQKey is not present in the map and if cdKey is present display a message.  <s:if test="%{#map['cyQKey']==null && #map.key.equalsIgnoreCase('cdKey')}">
    <h4><s:text name="property.msg.eheader"></s:text>
       <s:property value="%{nYValue}" />
    </h4>
   </s:if>

Answer (score 0):

If map is an action attribute with a `getMap()` getter, you don't have to use `#`; also `getCurrentYear()` becomes `currentYear` in OGNL.

This

```xml
<s:elseif test="%{map[currentYear]==null && map.key.equalsIgnoreCase('cdKey')}">
```

should be enough, but note that this would be way more simple (and elegant) if done serverside, in a

```
public boolean isValueEqualToCdKey(){ ... }
```

method, with

```xml
<s:elseif test="isValueEqualToCdKey" >
```

Comment: Hi, The above solution didn't work for me.  I have the map with getter and setter methods                                             private Map<String, List<JavaBean>> map=new LinkedHashMap<String, List<JavaBean>>();            removing #didnt work

Comment: First of all, separate the tests. Put (before the s:if / s:else) an s:property with the year test, and another with the key equality test, and see which one fails

Comment: I added s:if and else if as mentionsed but it didnt work <s:if test="%{map[currentYear]==null}">
         AA
        </s:if>
       <s:elseif test="%{map.key.equalsIgnoreCase('cdKey')}">
        Abc
       </s:elseif>
       <s:elseif test="%{map[currentYear]==null}">
        ABCDE
       </s:elseif>

Comment: So none of the tests work. Post more code (cdKey, ecc) or try doing it serverside that is safer and more elegant

Answer (score 0):

If List> map=new LinkedHashMap>();
is called in jsp like

```
<s:property value="#map.[#key]"/>
```